# SQLAlchemy - accessing columns of child model through parent model (one-to-one relation)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two models and one-to-one relationship between them. I would like to access columns of `ItemData` through `Item` (e.g. `item = Item(); item.value`). I tried to overwrote `__getattr__`, but this method is intensively used by SQLAlachemy base model. Any help appreciated.

```
class Item(Model):
    __tablename__ = "item_data"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    data = relationship("ItemData", back_populates="_item", uselist=False,
                        foreign_keys="ItemData._item_id")

class ItemData(Model):
    __tablename__ = "items_data"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    _item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("items.id"))
    _item = relationship("Item", back_populates="data",
                            foreign_keys=[_item_id])

    value = Column(Integer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing class decorator which should be apply to Item.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

def direct_data_getter(cls):
    '''Provide direct access to attributes of data.'''
    fields = set(cls.data_cls.__mapper__.columns.keys()) - set(dir(cls))
    for field in fields:
        method = hybrid_property(
            lambda self, field=field: getattr(self.data, field)
        )
        setattr(cls, field, method)
    return cls
```